# Compile single file vue.js component (*.vue) : problem with the name (defaults to app.js)

Tags: vue.js, webpack

**(npm vue -V => 3.2.1)**
I'm trying to compile a single file component `test1.vue` to a `*.js` file(s) in order to include it in an existing project. My intention is to get a `test1.js`file (and in production mode the `chunk-vendors.js` file).
What I tried until now:

> vue build ./src/test1.js

with result:

[image: vue build]

I don't want the file to be `app.js` so I put:

```
module.exports = {
  filenameHashing: false,
  chainWebpack: config => {
  config.entryPoints.delete('app')
  delete config.entry.app
  config.entry('test1')
    .add('./src/test1.js')
    .end()
}
```

}

into `vue.config.js` and got this:

[image]

so far so good!

When I try

> vue-cli-service build src/test1.js --mode development --name test1

I get always `app.js`. Is there a way to get the `test1` name in development mode also?

---

P.S. Manual rename in the file system is a (not nice) solution I know of.
(I could not put `vue-cli-service` tag to this post as it requires 1500 reputation. wow!)

Comment: look at the start of the post: vue.js -V => 3.2.1. And yes vue-cli 3 - right.

Comment: sorry, i typed vue -V on the terminal and got 3.2.1

Comment: yes thanks - I corrected the post now. The vue.js versioni is Vue.js v2.5.17. But it does not play a role in this case I think.

Comment: have you tried doing `vue-cli-service build --target lib --name test1 ./src/test1.js`

Comment: alternatively, you can use `vue-cli-service build --target wc --name my-element ./src/test1.js`, which should also come with demo usages for development

Comment: I'll try it right now ... does lib and wc generate the same js code? In other words do I get the same component, that I can include in another page? And does this code contains the vue.js itself - as in the case without target parameters?

Comment: In web component mode (`wc`), Vue is externalized. This means the bundle will not bundle Vue even if your code imports Vue. The bundle will assume Vue is available on the host page as a global variable.

Comment: I did vue-cli-service build --target lib --name test1 ./src/test1.js --mode development
and got test1.common.js, test1.umd.js

Comment: ... but I cannot run it without extras - commonjs or umd.
In the "normal" case I can just plug it into existing page and it loads vue.js and itself without problems.